# Is it possible to make all components pads NPTH in Eagle for a multilayer PCB?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

Using Eagle for a two sided PCB design.

One requirement is that all components pads to be non plated through holes (NPTH) and vias are to be PTH before starting autoroute.

Can someone tell me how to make all component pads NPTH in Eagle for multilayer (or 2 layer) PCB?

Comment: NPTH is non-*plated* through-hole. Also, "pad" and "via" are not acronyms and should not be written in all caps. What is "S/W"?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I assume you are planning to use through hole components (otherwise this wouldnt make any sense at all), why do you have a concern about pads on each side being connected to each other when they will be connected by the component leads anyway?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying.

Comment: As a hobbyist able to make  one sided pcb @ home & unable to make two sided (as  complex process for PTH). 
   And this design is a little complex to fit only in bottom route and having little more  unrouted tracks (so many jumpers).  
   Hence plan to route all jumpers (unrouted tracks) manually on the top layer using VIAS. 
   So during soldering I know only have to solder VIAS properly and components PADs are solder as single sided.(as PADs are difficult to solder on both side)
 Please let me know If possible to do the same (that is PADs as NPTH & VIAS as PTH).